# Adding delay at Start(), only then calling Update()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm learning Unity and have a problem, whose answer I can't seem to find an answer to on the internet.
In my game I want to add a delay at the complete start, so it doesn't do anything and only then start calling the Update function. I know I most likely could find a way to declare a timer and every time Update is called ask, if timer has elapsed, but I'm trying to look if it's possible to stop at start, and then continue like nothing happened.

I have tried using coroutines, but from the limited knowledge I have, I think coroutines are running alongside the code over several frames and that means Update is already being called. In one post somewhere I saw a mention about some timers?, so maybe that could work, however I couldnt understand it.
Please ask me any questions if I need to be more specific and thank u for your time.

Comment: Think it would help a lot when you tell what conditions it needs to meet to start the `Update` function. As now you could have a lot of different solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to make use of the fact that the `Start` method can return an `IEnumerator` and run as a coroutine. `Start` is always called before any `Update` so, we disable the MonoBehaviour, and once we've delayed the desired amount of time, re-enable the MonoBehaviour.

If you know the amount of time to delay, and that won't ever change, then one of the simplest examples would be:

```cs
IEnumerator Start ( )
{
    enabled = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds ( 3 ); // fixed delay
    enabled = true;
}
```

If you wanted the amount of time to be determined by an Inspector field, or even an external script, you could extend that to:

```cs
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float delayTime = 3.0f;

    IEnumerator Start ( )
    {
        Debug.Log ( $"First <color=#00ffff>Start</color> time : <color=#ffff>{Time.time}</color>" );
        enabled = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds ( delayTime );
        Debug.Log ( $"Delayed <color=#00ffff>Start</color> time : <color=#ffff>{Time.time}</color>" );
        enabled = true;
    }

    private void Update ( )
    {
        Debug.Log ( $"First <color=#00ffff>Update</color> time : <color=#ffff>{Time.time}</color>" );
        enabled = false;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: as soon as you set `enabled = false;` the Coroutine will no be executed anymore ;)

Comment: I didn't down-vote at all ;) I see I was wrong the API states it: `Coroutines are also stopped when the MonoBehaviour is destroyed or if the GameObject the MonoBehaviour is attached to is disabled. Coroutines are not stopped when a MonoBehaviour is disabled.` so a coroutine might even be better here ;)

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it. I tried calling Start as a coroutine before, however I didn't know I had to disable the MonoBehaviour.

Comment: And also thanks for showing how to show the times in console, didn't know about that before.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable ([`enabled = false`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html)) the component (so `Update` will not be called) and use [`Invoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) to enable that component after a delay. `Invoke` is one of the exceptions which is also working on disabled components

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float delay = 3.0f;

    private void Start ()
    {
        enabled = false;
        Invoke(nameof(Enable), delay);
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        // ...
    }

    private void Enable()
    {
        enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, worked for me. I had to study up on SerializeField because of it, so now I have something new in my arsenal.